# Nested Fragment auto-creation

Tags: android, android-fragments

**I got a fragment A containing a child fragment B. How is the correct way to create and add the child fragment B in fragment A so that any android-magic works?**

Currently I initialise child fragment B in constructor of fragment A and add it in onCreateView of fragment A (via FragmentTransaction.replace)
This works fine for the first time. But if the fragment is paused/resumed fragment A constructor is called, creating child fragment B and additionally android creates child fragment B automatically. So there are 2 child fragment B... I think it would be best to somehow use child fragment B created from android.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the `Fragment B`  exists

```
Fragment b = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b_container);
  if(b == null) {
    //initialize the fragment transaction here...
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add information where this code should be? Definitely not in constructor. Maybe onCreate or onCreateView?

Comment: where are you calling the nested fragment ? (onCreateView)

Comment: Now I check savedInstanceState in onCreateView, if != null getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG"). else initialise fragment with new FragmentB(). Initialising should be changed to FragmentB.getNewInstance() as far as I remember... Most importantly whats the correct way so that the android-framework magic does work?